# ASP.NET WebMethod with jQuery json, is there a size limit?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm calling a webmethod using jquery, the webmethod returns a chunk of HTML that's then loaded into a div.

It works fine up until a certain size of chunk then it's doesn't work at all.  It seems to stop working if the chunk of html is above 70KB.

The jQuery I'm using is:

```
 $(".letterBtn").live("click", function() {
    $("#divLoading").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Search",
        data: "{sFor:" + "'" + this.id + "'" + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#divOut").html(msg.d);
            $("#divLoading").html('');
        }
    });
});
```

The webmethod is similiar to this

```
  <WebMethod()> _ Public Shared Function Search(ByVal sFor As String) As String
    Dim htmlString As String = "<div>some html</div>"
    Return htmlString
End Function
```

I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work for larger HTML chunks.  Does anybody have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: why do you have datatype as JSON if you are returning HTML?

Comment: Are you sure the server isn't throwing an error? there's a default size limit on the json serializer on the .net side.

Comment: The server isn't throwing an error, I can step through the webmethod and see the string, if I put an alert in the js It doesn't seem to get that far.  I've changed the datatype.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

found what I was after, the default setting seems to be 100k, I set the following in my web.config file.  I think I'll rethink the html chunks now, it's doesn't seem like the best solution.

```
<webServices>
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="10000000"/>
</webServices>
```

Comment: The full path is

 <system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
   <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization  .../>

Comment: Lifesaver, this question & answer just enabled us to identify an annoyingly intermittent bug