# Debugging Web Service that fails as JSON but not as XML

Tags: json, web-services

I have a webservice method that if I call directly via url GET returns XML without issue.

However, POST to that same url with Content-Type Json, it fails.

I think I can figure out the issue (I'm guessing it's an encoding or bad character somewhere in there) but I don't know how to debug the problem.

If I set a breakpoint in the webservice, it runs to completion. The failure appears to be happening AFTER the method returns, but BEFORE the json is returned to the caller.

How can I get in between to trace the error?

Please let me know if I can provide more context to help, but I really just need to know how to get in there.

EDIT:
The web service is configured to receive POST and return JSON and in fact DOES correctly return JSON in some cases. However, there are certain calls that are failing, so I need a way to trace this or debug it somehow and figure out why some calls are not working.

Answer (score 0):

The web service is likely not configured to receive POST requests, especially if you are receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed response status.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but I'm sorry I should have mentioned that the web service does work sometimes, but in other calls it doesn't. so it's not a configuration issue (I don't think). I updated the description, thanks for helping me realize this ommission.

Comment: did you write this web service or is it an external site? if the former, please show us some back end code. if the latter, show your request and the responses, but it's unlikely we can do much.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't find a way to debug or intercept the request to find the exact answer, it turns out the problem was the size of the content being returned by the webservice. Following this answer: [ASP.NET WebMethod with jQuery json, is there a size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179986/asp-net-webmethod-with-jquery-json-is-there-a-size-limit)

and increasing the json limit fixed the issue!

Is there a way I could have trapped this to find the error without just guessing it was a size limit?